# Ember transitionTo and set controller attribute in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have Ember code to transitionTo some route & I want to set controllerAttr1 on my.route

```
this.get('router').transitionTo("my.route").then(function (newRoute) {
    newRoute.controller.set("controllerAttr1", controllerAttr1); // This code is called later
});
```

In my.route, I have a check for controller.controllerAttr1

```
model: function (params) {

},

setupController: function setupController(controller, model) {
    // Issue us below check is executed before the callback code which sets "controllerAttr1"
    if (controller.controllerAttr1) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

However, my issue is this check for controller.controllerAttr1 happens before the callback code is executed

```
newRoute.controller.set("controllerAttr1", controllerAttr1);
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/#asynchronous-transitions

> Because transitions so often involve the resolution of asynchronous
>   data, all transitions in router.js, are performed asynchronously,
>   leveraging the RSVP promise library. For instance, the value returned
>   from a call to transitionTo is a Transition object with a then method,
>   adhering to the Promise API. Any code that you want to run **after the
>   transition has finished** must be placed in the success handler of .then

so you can not use success hander of transitionTo. `controller` instance is available only in setupController hook, so answer depends on `controllerAttr1` where and how will you get this value.

Comment: How do I reexecute the model / setupController hooks after the then callback is executed

Comment: If you could explain our use cases then there will be better way of fixing it. re-executing is not good. but still if you want to redo all the work, that just now completed. well then there is `refresh` in route, that will do..

Comment: The scenario is the one I have described initially. So a transition happens to my.route (which executes some code in model / setupController) hooks & later the then() callback is executed which sets some controller property on my.route. But since the logic was executed earlier in setupController, my code does not work as expected

Comment: Now if I use refresh on the route, will it have the updated controller property i.e. controllerAttr1. So I'll set some new property in the then() callback, listen to it on my controller & then have a refresh in my route

Comment: yes. you can.  why do you require some `then() callback after transition is completed`, instead you can do it beforeModel hook and set some property in route and use that in setupController hook.

Comment: I do not completely understand you. But this call for transition & then callback is coming from some external app/engine. I just need to react to that in my app.